# double precision - pow()

Tags: c++, double

I want to calculate ***[n^(1/k)]*** where `n` is `long long` and `2 <= k <= lg(n)`; k is integer.

I thought may be I could use this:

```
long long d = pow(n,1.0/k)-1;
while(power(d,k) < n)
    d++;
d--;
```

but it may overflow `long long` at the last step.

Is it guaranteed that `d` will be pow(n,1.0/k) rounded down if I write:

```
long long d = long long(pow(n,1.0/k));
```

If not, what is an easy & safe way to calculate `floor(pow(n,1.0/k))`

Comment: If you want to calculate `floor(pow(n,1.0/k))` why dont you use `floor(pow(n,1.0/k))` for it?

Comment: @yi_H: `k <= log(k)` I think.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski: that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @PlasmaHH : I thought maybe the real value is `4-eps` for example, and the goal is 3 therefore. but `floor(pow(n,1.0/k))` may give 4. can't?

Comment: @yi_H: I know. I don't know what else it could be. WolframAlpha says `lg` is interpreted as `log`.

Comment: Your `long long(pow(...))` notation is pure C++; it is not valid in C (and since `long long` wasn't in standard C++98 or C++03, it is marginally debatable even in C++).  Also, isn't `floor(pow(n, 1.0/k))` the simplest and safest way to calculate `floor(pow(n, 1.0/k))`?  There is a `floor()` function in the standard C++ (and C) libraries.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : The problem is not compatibility with `C`, you can replace `long long` with `int`, the problem holds. About `floor()` the problem is maybe the number given to it is not precise, the real answer may be `4-eps` and `pow()` gives `4+eps` to `floor()`

Comment: The cast notation `type(value)` is specific to C++; C requires `(type)value` instead.  You've lost me on how the precision is an issue.  If `pow()` is giving you imprecise answers, then it doesn't much matter what else goes on.  If `pow()` is precise, then I don't see that `floor()` has any issues.

Comment: I didn't say `floor()` or `pow()` are my problem. I wanted exact value of floor(pow(n,1/k)) where floor() and pow are mathematical functions not `C` or `C++`. Using just `C++` functions `floor(pow(n,1.0/k))` is easy but not safe for that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the implementation of `pow` in your stdlib exactly, you cannot be absolutely sure that

```
floor(pow(n,1.0/k)) or (long long)pow(n,1.0/k)
```

returns the correct result. `1.0/k` introduces a small inaccuracy and that plus the inaccuracy of `pow` (unavoidable due to the representation of `double`s) may just move the result of `pow()` past the integer threshold if `n` is a `k`<sup>th</sup> power or very close to one.

An example using Haskell's `(**)`, which does the same thing as `pow()` from `math.h`, but it might have a different implementation:

```
Prelude> 3^37-1 :: Int
450283905890997362
Prelude> fromIntegral it ** (1.0/37)
3.0000000000000004
```

It will however always be at least very close to the correct result, so you can use it as the starting point for a quick correction if necessary.

```
// assumes k > 2
long long r = (long long)pow(n,1.0/k);
while (n/power(r+1,k-k/2) >= power(r+1,k/2)) ++r;
while (n/power(r,k-k/2) < power(r,k/2)) --r;
```

where `power(a,b)` is an integer power function (could be `round(pow(a,b))` for example, or exponentiation by repeated squaring). By raising `r` resp `r+1` only to the `k-1`<sup>th</sup> power, overflow is avoided (except possibly if `r` is 1, you can deal with that special case easily if necessary by testing `k < 64 && n < (1ull << k)`).

Of course the tests for the special cases and the fixup cost time and in almost all cases do nothing above `floor(pow(n,1.0/k))`, so it may not be worth it.

Comment: Correct, in a few cases it could, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for guarantees. Unfortunately, there are very few guarantees when it comes to types in C/C++. An exact size for these datatypes is not defined, though you'll find that `long long` is normally 64 bits. However, I believe that `1.0` will by default be a `float`, which normally has 32 bits. There are both `float pow(float base, float exponent)` and `double pow(double base, double exponent)` and I'm not certain that C++ will understand which one you want to use unless you specify it. Thus, you might lose precision when you convert. Oh, and by the way, even `double` might be less precise than a `long long`, since it stores the exponent as well.

Another problem is that floating point conversion might be inexact even when you think that it shouldn't be. I've had cases where I've read an integer into a floating point variable from `stdin`, and then immediately converted it back to an `int`, and found out that it was rounded down from one integer value to the one below! To avoid this, you should add a small epsilon prior to the typecast. The size of the epsilon should be determined based on the precision of the variables and the size of the numbers you're working with.

Answer (score -1):

pow() returns a double, i think that's what you've missed